# Rails 3.2.21 & Rspec 3 upgrade and a lot of expectations fail - why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec3

**Rephrased question**

It seems the original question wasn't clear. Let me retry.

In a RSpec controller test, how do I stub a method of an object that is not accessible directly? Specifically:

```
# foo_controller
def show
  @object = Foo.find(params[:id])
  @action = current_user.actions.create(foo: @object, ... )     # log view action
  # ...
end

# action.rb model
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :object    # actually polymorphic, but not for this example
before_validation :cache_values
def cache_values
  if self.foo   # safety check
    # cache some attributes in action since Foo instances might get deleted
    self.attribute1 = self.foo.attribute1
    self.attribute2 = self.foo.attribute2  
    # ...      
  end
end
```

In the controller test I want to stub `Foo` since it is expensive to create. In Rails 3 and rspec 2.14, I was able to do

```
expect(Foo).to receive(:find).with("123") { mock_model(Foo) }
```

and the mocked instance of `Foo` would be accessed in the `cache_values` method. However, this does not work any more with Rails 3.2 and rspec 3.1. If the `action` were also a mock I could use

```
expect(@mock_action).to receive(:foo) { mock_model(Foo) }
```

and I realize this is probably the best way for a controller test, but nevertheless I would like to understand how I can "catch" ActiveModel association database lookups at a lowermost level like above.

Comment: Did you follow the upgrade guide? http://rspec.github.io/upgrading-from-rspec-2/ If there are any new failures in RSpec 3 that weren't in RSpec 2, and the upgrade process didn't give you a deprecation warning, then we consider that a bug and we'd ask you to report it to github.

Comment: I installed transpec and it reformatted most of the syntax changes, but I did not know about rspec 2.99. My main gripe is that (apparently) I cannot use the above `expect(Foo).to receive(:find)...` syntax to mock AR associations any more. Or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Please open an issue -- that syntax should work for any kind of object.

Comment: Before I do so - is it possible that the ActiveModel internal syntax for accessing `has_many`type child objects changed between 3.0 and 3.2 so that this syntax simply doesn't work any more for Rails? How/where can I check this?

Comment: No idea, I haven't used Rails in years.

Answer (score 1):

Rspec 3 does not support `mock_model` method; it has been extracted into a separate gem [rspec-activemodel-mocks](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-activemodel-mocks)

Ref: http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3#extracted_activemodel_mocks_support

Including this gem should fix the failing tests.

Comment: Yes, I have this gem (sorry, forgot to mention, updated my text above). The error is not about mock_model, the problem is that my expect / allow does not "catch" the database query.